# Not found when setup git server on HTTP protocol

Tags: git, http, apache2

OS: ubuntu 20.04 desktop

web server: Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
Alias /git /var/www/html

<Location />
    Options ExecCGI Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to setup HTTP server on my computer, and chrome browser can successfully shows the repo.

[image]

However, `git clone` always show `not found`

```
$ git clone http://localhost/test/base.git/
Cloning into 'base'...
fatal: repository 'http://localhost/test/base.git/' not found
```

what can be the problem? Apache2 log shows below

```
127.0.1.1:80 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2021:11:04:34 +0800] "GET /test/base.git/info/refs/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 432 "-" "git/2.25.1"
```

Comment: If you try from the command line something like `wget 'http://localhost/test/base.git/config'`, does it work? That's more similar than the browser test to what you're doing with git.

Comment: @Mort it works, and successfully download the correct config file. Just git clone doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
```

It seems, apaches just replace string of alias. i miss `/` in this option, the correct should be

```
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

BTW, i solved it by looking at `/var/log/apache2`